# How to create a lookup where the type of each value depends on the key?

Tags: typescript, generics

I'm trying to create a lookup where each key determines the type of the corresponding value.

Consider this code:

```
type Language =  'en' | 'de';

// Language-specific parser
type Parser<TLanguage extends Language> = (text: string, language: TLanguage) => any;

// Lookup that contains a typed parser for each language
const parsers: { [language in Language]: Parser<language> } = {
  'de': () => null, // Dummy values
  'en': () => null,
};
```

The idea is that for each `Language`, `parsers` contains a language-specific parser *strongly typed for that particular language*.

This assignment works as expected:

```
const englishParser: Parser<'en'> = parsers.en;
```

But this assignment doesn't work, and I can't figure out why. My goal is to write type-safe code without type assertions.

```
function test<TLanguage extends Language>(language: TLanguage) {
  // Error:
  // Type '{ en: Parser<"en">; de: Parser<"de">; }[TLanguage]' is not assignable
  // to type 'Parser<TLanguage>'.
  const parser: Parser<TLanguage> = parsers[language]; //
}
```

Here's [a TypeScript Playground link that demonstrates the problem](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAMghgOwOYFc5OgXilA5BBXKAHzwBMJcBuAKBoHp7ZFV0IBaAZ0gGMBLAGZ8eUMHABOnCOJqhIUAAoSp4gDwAVeMjQYoEAB7ACZTs21sAfFGwAKI4YBcUTsHF9kAGigAbFjohOmn5sAJTWVoggtAxMMAD2cQDWKGBQwAAWcMBQPHEIwHDupnBp4BBkosrSUAJx4npwPOk+wRg0uQgulZLSnE4A3lAA2r7muu5mrBgAuk5KPWqjUxBWAL7WUP00OLgUuE42YZhWCCje3l6MUAAiKAC2dyBQAG5w3igQnNt4BPtQh+EoKdzh4aKtold1Ok+KYAO51RKcAB07TyXQISG8MPS8xUcyqanwhCs2DEC2RBGiAhQCB4wD4eTSn2AGi0yz0hmMpjZ-gsNiW-kCPNCm2+kOhpjIcU+hGy8PEiRROA6XTJeMUBNZrRWGzVvRG2umtFWNCAA).

Answer (score 0):

You need a type cast in there :

```
function test<TLanguage extends Language>(language: TLanguage) {
  const parser: Parser<TLanguage> = parsers[language] as Parser<TLanguage>; 
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAMghgOwOYFc5OgXilA5BBXKAHzwBMJcBuAKDoHp7ZFV0IBaAZ0gGMBLAGZ8eUMHABOnCOJqhIUAAoSp4gDwAVeMjQYoEAB7ACZTs21sAfFGwAKI4YBcUTsHF9kAGigAbFjohOmn5sAJTWVoggtDSMsAD2cQDWKGBQwAAWcMBQPHEIwHDupnBp4BBkosrSUAJx4npwPOk+wRg0uQgulZLSnE4A3lAA2r7muu44WqwYALpOSj1qo9MQVgC+1lD9NDi4FLhONmGYVgBEmXzep16xACIoALYPIFAAbnDeKBCcO3gEB1AjuEoOc+NcaGtorF1Ok+KYAO51RKcAB07TyXQISG8cPSCxU8yqalOBFOVmwYkWqII0QEKAQPGAfDyaW+wA0U38ekMxlMnMsNmW-kC-IwYW2vw6XUpKk2Mt6I1aEBmUDgpnx0g5Sos0RwUri3ggKO8cSQNnl4hCELosjZNhJCFOISoQA)

Comment: Thank you; I'm aware that I can use a type assertion here. The point of my question was how to avoid that. I've edited the question to make this explicit.

Comment: @DanielWolf that's a place that you can't avoid assertion. That's a known thing of Typescript.

Comment: Do you have a source that confirms this is a known problem (a TS issue or something similar)? I couldn't find anything, but maybe I didn't search for the right keywords.

Comment: @DanielWolf Didn't check Github for this but seen similar questions.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the generics:

```
function test(language: Language) {
    const parser = parsers[language];
}
```

Explanation as to why what you try to do cannot work:

The type of `parsers` does not retain the information with which you constructed it. In the declaration `{ [language in Language]: Parser<language> }` there is a clear dependence between the name of the property and the type of the property.

However, this type gets resolved to:

```
const parsers: {
    en: Parser<"en">;
    de: Parser<"de">;
}
```

Which can be seen as

```
const parsers: {
    en: BlackBoxA;
    de: BlackBoxB;
}
```

So if you access a property with the key `'en' | 'de'` you will simply get `BlackBoxA | BlackBoxB`, or here `Parser<"en"> | Parser<"de">` which cannot necessarily be assigned to your more specific type `Parser<TLanguage>`, which is just one of the two and incompatible with the other one.

Comment: (Unless you want to return something using the type parameter from the function, i guess)

Comment: Are you sure it really makes no error? It doesn't seem to be the case with TypeScript 4.0.2 at least....

Comment: @C.Champagne Apparently the VS Code TS language server does not catch some errors if the file is not embedded in a project structure. I removed the type annotation (it does not help anyway).

Comment: @H.B. What I need is a parser of the correct generic type. I'm aware that simply omitting the type in the assignment makes the code compile. But as you observed, the resulting constant won't have the correct generic type.

Comment: @DanielWolf: You will always be lacking information to narrow the type of the parser in a meaningful way, regardless of whether you have generics or not. What do you hope to accomplish by getting a variable of type `Parser<T>`? It just tells you that you have some kind of parser.